# In the American Congress, how does a motion come forward to be voted on without the support of the Speaker or Senate majority leader)?

Tags: congress, senate

At least in the Senate it´s easier given the majority leader is not the chair, that would be the president pro tempore or the vice president. But in general, how does this happen if push comes to shove?

Also, if it is relevant, the kind of motion can be anything, to pass a bill, confirm a nominee, to make a normal resolution, to dethrone the speakership (or hypothetically to choose a new president pro tempore), etc, whichever one you know best.

Comment: This question is a better fit for [Politics.SE].

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment, the legal aspect of this question begins and ends with the constitution's provision that each house determines its own rules.  The specific content of the rules at any given point might conceivably be on topic here but is certainly on topic at [Politics.SE]; any other aspect of the question is off topic here but probably on topic there.

Comment: @phoog is probably correct on where to get an answer, but for some reading look up “discharge petition”.